# xcopy.exe exists in every Windows system?

Tags: xcopy

Can I be sure that `xcopy.exe` exists in every Windows system (7+) and that it can always be found in the system `PATH` (e.g. `C:\windows\system32`)?

Comment: Of course even if it is in System32 you can't be *sure* that PATH will *always* be correct so maybe call it with `%systemroot%\System32\xcopy` See [xcopy is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273427/xcopy-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)

Comment: A future-proof answer to this question is not possible. Theoretically, Microsoft could decide to remove it at any time.

Comment: Could I distribute xcopy.exe myself with the installer of my app? (And put into a custom app directory).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Powershell script *(needs to be run as admin)* can be used to check for the presence of `xcopy` and copy it from a network server if not present; if path doesn't exist, it will create it as well.

```powershell
$xcopypath = 'C:\Windows\System32\xcopy.exe'
$xcopy = Test-Path $xcopypath
$server = \\NAS\xcopy.exe
$envpath = Get-ChildItem Env:
$path = $envpath.Value

if($xcopy){
    write-host -ForegroundColor Green "xCopy present"
}while($xcopy -ne 'True'){
      write-host -ForegroundColor red "xCopy not present"
      Copy-Item $server -path C:\Windows\System32
      $xcopy = Test-Path C:\Windows\System32\xcopy.exe
}


if($path.Contains('C:\Windows\system32\xcopy.exe')){
    write-host -ForegroundColor Green "Path exists"
}else{
     write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow 'Path does not exist. Creating path'
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("xCopy.exe", "$xcopypath", "Machine")
}
```

Comment: Please reconsider before putting random stuff in system folders, even if this random stuff is provided by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it exists in pretty much every windows, not sure about win 95 and 98 but in the otheres it is all present.